# Is this kind of puppy's stool normal?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

Is it normal that 13 days old puppy's stool is liquid and with foam (little bubbles) ?

Today I notice that one of the 4 puppies made that kind of stool and at the same time the puppy screamed loudly  like if someone were hurting the puppy. So the puppy felt pain while doing it.

Why?

Should I take the puppy to the vet? Or is something passenger?

> [image]

Comment: No it's not. Take the puppy to the vet asap, as diarrhoea in such a young pup can be dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never had contact with such young puppy as the fastest you can get one is 8(or 7) weeks old, but if it's stool is different from the rest of puppies, I would contact vet, just because of how young the dog is.

But for older dog, that kind of stool is not normal. My puppy got that kind of runny stool after 3rd dose of vaccines, but we gave him overcooked rice, with a little bit of coal, and next day, overcooked rice,chicken and carrot, and it went back to normal. Though he was 12 weeks old. And I'm not sure what kind of food very young puppies can eat.